# I want to check Internet Connection

Tags: android

HELP ME.....
I used this code for checking Internet Connection but in every states it returned "false"

```
 boolean check;
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
    =(ConnectivityManager)this.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
 NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
  check=(activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected());
```

Comment: Instead of `activeNetworkInfo.isConnected()`, you should check `activeNetworkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()` for the safer side.

Comment: if you got answer Accept answer so other can get help from this :)

Answer (score 1):

try this code

this code is checking all type of network connection like wifi,network data,etc...
just need to call this method when you want to check internet connection like

```
 if (isConnectingToInternet(this)) { 
   //do internet available here 
 }
 else{
   //internet not available here 
 }


public static boolean isConnectingToInternet(Context _context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivity != null) {
        NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null)
            for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                    Log.d("Network",
                            "NETWORKnAME: " + info[i].getTypeName());
                    return true;
                }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You should include brief about the resolution you are suggesting.

Comment: @paresh yes thanks next time before answering i will keep in mind

Comment: consider accepting my answer so this can be help other also

Answer (score 0):

```
protected boolean isNetworkConnected() {
    Context ctx = this;
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (info != null)
        return info.isAvailable();
    else
        return false;
}
```

also set below permission in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: You should include brief about the resolution you are suggesting.

Comment: I set them and used every code you think but,my answer is always false or true that they are not true Answer???

Comment: maybe something wronge in your calling.can you put your code here

Answer (score 0):

try this ,

create a class ConnectionDetector .

```
public class ConnectionDetector {

private Context _context;
public ConnectionDetector(Context context){
    this._context = context;
}

/**
 * Checking for all possible Internet providers
 * **/
public boolean isConnectingToInternet(){
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
      if (connectivity != null)
      {
          NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
          if (info != null)
              for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                  if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                  {
                      return true;
                  }

      }
      return false;
   }

}
```

when you want to check internet in any activity/fragment/others use this code..

```
 ConnectionDetector conn = new ConnectionDetector(ActivityName.this);
                    if(conn.isConnectingToInternet()){
                    // Do your Network Operations 
                    }else{
                        // No Network , show a dialog , etc
                    }
```

Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```